# Reusing type definitions with JSONProvider?

Tags: json, f#, type-providers, f#-data

I'm using the JSONProvider from FSharp-Data to automatically create types for a webservice that I'm consuming using sample responses from the service.

However I'm a bit confused when it comes to types that are reused in the service, like for example there is one api method that return a single item of type X while another returns a list of X and so on. Do I really have to generate multiple definitions for this, and won't that mean that I will have duplicate types for the same thing?

So, I guess what I'm really asking, is there a way to create composite types from types generated from JSON samples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you call `JsonProvider` separately with separate samples, then you will get duplicate types for the same things in the sample. Sadly, there is not much that the F# Data library can do about this.

One option that you have would be to pass multiple samples to the `JsonProvider` at the same time (using the `SampleIsList` parameters). In that case, it tries to find one type for all the samples you provide - but it will also share types with the same structure among all the samples.

I assume you do not want to get one type for all your samples - in that case, you can wrap the individual samples with additional JSON object like this (here, the real samples are the records nested under "one" and "two"):

```
type J = JsonProvider<"""
  [ { "one": { "person": {"name": "Tomas"} } },
    { "two": { "num": 42, "other":  {"name": "Tomas"} } } ]""", SampleIsList=true>
```

Now, you can run the `Parse` method and wrap the samples in a new JSON object using "one" or "two", depending on which sample you are processing:

```
let j1 = """{ "person": {"name": "Tomas"} }"""
let o1 = J.Parse("""{"one":""" + j1 + "}").One.Value

let j2 = """{ "num": 42, "other": {"name": "Tomas"} }"""
let o2 = J.Parse("""{"two":""" + j2 + "}").Two.Value
```

The "one" and "two" records are completely arbitrary (I just added them to have two separate names). We wrap the JSON before parsing it and then we access it using the `One` or `Two` property. However, it means that `o1.Person` and `o2.Other` are now of the same type:

```
o1.Person = o2.Other
```

This returns `false` because we do not implement equality on JSON values in F# Data, but it type checks - so the types are the same.

This is fairly complicated, so I would probably look for other ways of doing what you need - but it is one way to get shared types among multiple JSON samples.

Comment: Ah, I suspected this was the case, and yes, I will probably try to find (or build) something more natural and elegant. Would it be possible to extend JsonProvider (or any type provider) to support syntax like JsonProvider<MyType list> where MyType is a previously defined type from a sample (or perhaps any type like a DU)?

Comment: If you already had a manually defined type, you don't need a type provider. Just use JSON.NET or something similar.